# How to install a ceiling fan box in a plaster ceiling

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan, support

I'd like to install ceiling fans in a house with lath and plaster ceilings.  I've looked into [support boxes](https://www.homedepot.com/p/15-5-cu-in-Retrofit-Ceiling-Fan-Saf-T-Brace-0110000/204845572) at big box stores which attach to ceiling joists.  However, these kits are sized for drywall, and don't protrude deep enough to reach the surface of the plaster.

How do I safely mount the fan to the thicker plaster ceiling?

Comment: That kit has height adjustment on the box mounting stud. It's just the ticket.

Comment: @isherwood are you saying that the end support "spacers" can be positioned by rotation to allow the support rod to be closer to the ceiling and so the box to be positioned properly? "Properly" would be with outer edge in the plane of the living space side of the the ceiling although the box could be a little proud of the ceiling, right?

Comment: @isherwood would it be preferable to cut off part of the bottom of each spacer to allow the bar to fit closer to the attic side of the ceiling?

Comment: @isherwood or is there a spacer plate in the kit which fits between the back of the box and the bar to lower the box?

Comment: No. The nylon insert nut you see in the center of the box allows for depth adjustment.

Comment: Or, just use this deeper version of the same thing:  https://www.homedepot.com/p/21-5-cu-in-Saf-T-Brace-0140000/204845573